# I want to open bootstrap modal .net webform on button click

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, webforms, modalpopup

I had written code for modal popup but its not working, I am new to .net so i don't know how its work so please help me in that.. On clicking add button i want to open modal popup but its not working.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btn_add_new").click(function () {
            $('#UsersModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
     <asp:Button ID="btn_add_new" runat="server" Text="Add New"  CausesValidation="False" CssClass="button" data-target="#UsersModal"
                    />


<div class="modal fade" id="UsersModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModalTitle">
                    New User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbluname" Font-Size="Large" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" Font-Size="Large" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRememberMe" Text="Remember Me" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Save" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a html button like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" CssClass="button" 
 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UsersModal">Add New</button>
```

Your javascript is not required to open the modal.

The modal opens fine on my test page using your modal code.

Comment: @vegafire if this is the accepted answer, could you set it as accepted.